# If the Difference of Two Sequences Vanish, Does the Difference of the Powers of Those Two Sequences Vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are two complex sequences such that $|a_n - b_n| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Is it then true that

$| a_n^n - b_n^n | \to 0$

as $n \to \infty$?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Let $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas with a small tweak, the above can even be modified to show that the difference of the powers can be made to converge to any positive value of your choosing.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $a_n=n^{1/n}, ~ b_n=1$.